# Recaptcha control not loading on Sitecore 10.2

Tags: sitecore-forms, recaptcha

Getting the following in the dev tools console and the recaptcha control is not rendering.

`reCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: loadReCaptchas`

Recently upgraded from Sitecore 9.0.2 to 10.2. We upgraded the Sitecore Forms Extensions to version `sc10.1-4.0.2`. The ReCaptcha control will not load. On Content Management servers I am able to view the ReCaptcha image but the control itself will not load when viewing the form on a page.
When debugging, the output from the Recaptcha.cshtml looks like the following:

```
<div id="fxb_fe2d6775-2160-428c-9065-8e3f7565b206_Fields_d4073a01-591d-4e0d-8d09-2dc6d78e83a4__CaptchaValue_wrapper"></div>
<input id="fxb_fe2d6775-2160-428c-9065-8e3f7565b206_Fields_d4073a01-591d-4e0d-8d09-2dc6d78e83a4__CaptchaValue" name="fxb.fe2d6775-2160-428c-9065-8e3f7565b206.Fields[d4073a01-591d-4e0d-8d09-2dc6d78e83a4].CaptchaValue" type="hidden" class="fxt-captcha" data-val-required="Please confirm you are not a robot." data-val="true" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="fxb.fe2d6775-2160-428c-9065-8e3f7565b206.Fields[d4073a01-591d-4e0d-8d09-2dc6d78e83a4].CaptchaValue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var reCaptchaArray = reCaptchaArray || [];
  reCaptchaArray.push(
    function() {
      var _captchaInput = window.document.getElementById('fxb_fe2d6775-2160-428c-9065-8e3f7565b206_Fields_d4073a01-591d-4e0d-8d09-2dc6d78e83a4__CaptchaValue');
      window.grecaptcha.render('fxb_fe2d6775-2160-428c-9065-8e3f7565b206_Fields_d4073a01-591d-4e0d-8d09-2dc6d78e83a4__CaptchaValue_wrapper',
        {
          'sitekey': 'REMOVED-PROPERLY-ADDED',
          'callback': function(token) {
            _captchaInput.value = token;
          },
          'expired-callback': function(args) {
            _captchaInput.value = '';
          }
        });
    }
  );
</script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadReCaptchas&render=explicit&hl=en" async defer></script>
```

Any hints on what could be preventing the control from loading properly?
screenshot of the message in Console:[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you recaptcha icon at the right bottom corner of your screen?

Comment: If no then any browser console logs will be useful.

Comment: @Anton I will try your version difference suggestion below. I do not see any icons. When trying to submit the form, it does ask me to confirm I'm not a robot, but there's no option to do such thing. See screenshot above.

Comment: another guess: Do you still has same domain names? Do these domains are allowed for these domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is a missing callback function that should be called once the reCaptcha control is loaded. The function name is specified in the script tag:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadReCaptchas ...
```

In previous versions of Sitecore Forms Extensions the callback function was defined in the same `ReCaptcha.cshtml` file as the field HTML markup. Starting from version 9.2 this function exists in the file `/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts/formsextensions.validate.js` and it looks like the browser can't find this function on your page.

Please check the following potential reasons:

- You should see that the JavaScript file  `/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts/formsextensions.validate.js` loads correctly in the Network tab of browser Developer Tools. If this file does not exist or the request blocked, it will trigger this error.
- If the JavaScript file is loaded correctly, make sure that it is not cached and contains the function `loadReCaptchas`. You can compare your file with the [correct version in GitHub](https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts/formsextensions.validate.js).
- If you do not see any request to `formsextensions.validate.js` and there is no such `<script>` tag in the raw HTML output of you page, check that the processor `Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.JavascriptLoader` and the config [Feature.FormsExtensions.Processors.config](https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/App_Config/Include/Feature/FormsExtensions/Feature.FormsExtensions.Processors.config) are included in your Sitecore configs folder. Your page layout file should also contain the helper `@Html.RenderFormScripts()` before the closing `</body>` tag to include the necessary scripts for forms.

Comment: In my case, we were manually adding the sitecore javascript files instead of using `@Html.RenderFormScripts()`. Fixing this resolved the issue. Thank you for a very thorough response.